# Connecting Vault to SSO/OIDC Authelia

Tags: single-sign-on, hashicorp-vault

My Authelia is connected to an LDAP server, from which it retrieves all user information. There are no issues with connecting Vault directly to LDAP. I create groups in LDAP, then create corresponding groups in Vault and associate the necessary policies with them.

I went further to integrate Vault with Authelia. I already have experience integrating Authelia with other services, and I was able to integrate Vault with Authelia by specifying the default role during Vault authorization. Everything is functioning as expected.. However, I don't want to use the default role; instead, I want Vault to receive groups from SSO, just like it does with LDAP, and grant access according to the required policies. During the Vault with Authelia integration, I noticed that by default, Vault only requires OpenID for authentication. I understand that to implement my idea, I need Vault to also request user groups from Authelia. Authelia is configured to transmit groups:

```
      - id: vault
#        consent_mode: implicit
        description: HashiCorp Vault
        secret: 'my_secret'
        public: false
        authorization_policy: one_factor
        redirect_uris:
            - https://vault.example.com/oidc/callback
            - https://vault.examle.com/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback
        scopes:
            - openid
            - profile
            - groups
            - email
        userinfo_signing_algorithm: none
```

Perhaps someone has already performed a similar integration. I want to eliminate the need for users to manually specify their roles. Ideally, I want to get rid of the Vault login window entirely. When users open the Vault UI in their browser, I want them to be redirected to the Authelia login window. I have already implemented something similar using "access_control" in Authelia for services without authentication, but where access needs to be restricted to authorized users.

Comment: You can try Casdoor instead: https://casdoor.org/

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for isn't possible with the OIDC provider in vault. I've scoured the documentation and can't find any examples or evidence that this is possible.

Your best bet is to either use a single role and set it as the default or get your users to enter a role upon login.

Avoiding the login page entirely is not possible, as vault presents several auth methods and it needs to know which one you want when you go to log in.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You've only confirmed my concerns on this matter. Although it's quite strange. My SSO Authelia connects to LDAP, retrieves data from there, and simply transmits it to connected services. Vault doesn't request a group from the user during LDAP authentication but fetches it on its own. However, such a feature is not available through OIDC...

In general, Vault is more of a product for engineering tasks related to secret storage. For an ordinary user (meaning someone who has no idea what LDAP or OIDC is), Vault is not very user-friendly.